# 'worth the name' meaning? in following context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Several woman hardly had a married life **worth the name**, yet(at least among the higher castes) when their husbands died they were expected to commit sati.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom [**worthy of the name**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/worthy+of+the+name) means: meaningful enough to deserve the name. So if the women had a married life "hardly worth[y] of the name" it means their lives were not fulfilling/interesting/meaningful enough to be called "life."